# How to style a shiny app with CSS (file base)

Tags: css, r, shiny

Right now I'm doing a project for my university and I've tried to style this shiny app many times, but it seems like nothing has changed in the app. [image]. Even when I did put the `tags$head` in and link it with external file CSS, it didn't change anything in the app. I would like to know what is the problem and how to prevent this in the future.

Here is the code. Is there any way I can style it using CSS?

`

```
Define UI ----
ui <- navbarPage("Thai Economic",
             # Global Economic Development Page.
             tabPanel("Population",
                      id = "population",
                      h1("Thailand Population"),
                      br(),
                      plotlyOutput("thai_population_chart"),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("pop_line","Line Chart")),
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("button_id", "Bar Chart"))
                      ),
                      br(),
                      p("Over the last decade, Thailand's population has continued to grow steadily. 
                According to the World Bank, the population of Thailand in 2011 was approximately 68.3 million, 
                while the estimated population in 2020 was approximately 69.8 million. 
                This represents an increase of around 1.5 million people over the course of the decade. 
                Despite this growth, the rate of population increase in Thailand has been slowing down in recent years, 
                due in part to a declining birth rate and an aging population. Nonetheless, 
                Thailand remains one of the most populous countries in Southeast Asia, with a diverse population that includes a mix of ethnic groups, 
                religions, and languages.")
                      
             ),
             
             
             
             # Thailand GDP Page
             tabPanel("GDP",
                      h1("Thailand GDP"),
                      br(),
                      plotlyOutput("thai_gdp_chart"),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("gdp_line", "Line Chart")),
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("gdp_bar", "Bar Chart"))
                      ),
                      br(),
                      p("Thailand's...")
             ),
             
             # Poverty Page
             tabPanel("Poverty",
                      h1("Thailand Poverty"),
                      br(),
                      plotlyOutput("thai_poverty_chart"),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("pov_line", "Line Chart")),
                        column(width = 2, actionButton("poverty_bar", "Bar Chart"))
                      ),
                      br(),
                      p("Over the past decade....")
             ),
             
             # Import and Export goods and Service Page
             tabPanel("Import and Export goods and Service",
                      h1("Import and Export goods and Service"),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(width = 6, plotlyOutput("thai_imports_chart")),
                        column(width = 6, plotlyOutput("thai_export_chart"))
                      ),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(width = 3,
                               actionButton("im_line", "Line Chart"),
                               actionButton("im_bar", "Bar Chart")
                        ),
                        column(width = 3, offset = 6,
                               actionButton("ex_line", "Line Chart"),
                               actionButton("ex_bar", "Bar Chart")
                        ),
                      ),
                      br(),
                      p("Thailand is a major ...")
             ),
            
)`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to create a **www** subfolder of your app folder, and put the CSS file there. Then you can use `tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "mycssfile.css')` (don't write `www/mycssfile.css`).

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a way to change the CSS inline:

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(ui = navbarPage(title = "Thai Economic",
                         
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
      }"))
                         ),
                         
                 # Global Economic Development Page.
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Population",
                          id = "population",
                          h1("Thailand Population"),
                          br(),
                          plotlyOutput("thai_population_chart"),
                          br(),
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 2, actionButton("pop_line","Line Chart")),
                            column(width = 2, actionButton("button_id", "Bar Chart"))
                          ),
                          br(),
                          p("Over the last decade, Thailand's population has continued to grow steadily. 
                According to the World Bank, the population of Thailand in 2011 was approximately 68.3 million, 
                while the estimated population in 2020 was approximately 69.8 million. 
                This represents an increase of around 1.5 million people over the course of the decade. 
                Despite this growth, the rate of population increase in Thailand has been slowing down in recent years, 
                due in part to a declining birth rate and an aging population. Nonetheless, 
                Thailand remains one of the most populous countries in Southeast Asia, with a diverse population that includes a mix of ethnic groups, 
                religions, and languages.")
                
                 ),
                
                
                
                # Thailand GDP Page
                tabPanel("GDP",
                         h1("Thailand GDP"),
                         br(),
                         plotlyOutput("thai_gdp_chart"),
                         br(),
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 2, actionButton("gdp_line", "Line Chart")),
                           column(width = 2, actionButton("gdp_bar", "Bar Chart"))
                         ),
                         br(),
                         p("Thailand's...")
                ),
                
                # Poverty Page
                tabPanel("Poverty",
                         h1("Thailand Poverty"),
                         br(),
                         plotlyOutput("thai_poverty_chart"),
                         br(),
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 2, actionButton("pov_line", "Line Chart")),
                           column(width = 2, actionButton("poverty_bar", "Bar Chart"))
                         ),
                         br(),
                         p("Over the past decade....")
                ),
                
                # Import and Export goods and Service Page
                tabPanel("Import and Export goods and Service",
                         h1("Import and Export goods and Service"),
                         br(),
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 6, plotlyOutput("thai_imports_chart")),
                           column(width = 6, plotlyOutput("thai_export_chart"))
                         ),
                         br(),
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 3,
                                  actionButton("im_line", "Line Chart"),
                                  actionButton("im_bar", "Bar Chart")
                           ),
                           column(width = 3, offset = 6,
                                  actionButton("ex_line", "Line Chart"),
                                  actionButton("ex_bar", "Bar Chart")
                           ),
                         ),
                         br(),
                         p("Thailand is a major ...")
                ))
                
),
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
})
```

Alternatively, replace the `head` tag with the following code and place `custom.css` in the `www` folder:

```r
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
  )
```